# Showing the current location in ionic with OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

I try to show a road in a map + I want the user to be able to see himself on the map.

I have the following

```
constructor(){
 this.initUserPosition()
}

init(target = 'myMapid', zoom: number) {
private _map: Map
vectorLayer: VectorLayer
view: View
zoom: number

this.view = new View({
  center: [0, 0],
  zoom: zoom,
})

this._map = new Map({
  controls: [],
  target: target,
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM(),
    }),
  ],
  view: this.view,
})

new VectorLayer({
  map: this._map,
  source: new VectorSource({
    features: [this.positionFeature],
  }),
})
}
}
```

I did add the user location like the following.
*the `onUserPositionChanged$` is an observable that returns my coordinates like this `{lng: string, lat: string}`*

```
initUserPosition() {
  this.positionFeature = new Feature()
  this.positionFeature.setStyle(
    new Style({
      image: new CircleStyle({
        radius: 6,
        fill: new Fill({
          color: '#3399CC',
        }),
        stroke: new Stroke({
          color: '#fff',
          width: 2,
        }),
      }),
    }),
  )

  this._geolocationService.onUserPositionChanged$
    .pipe(takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll))
    .subscribe((coordinates) => {
      this.positionFeature.setGeometry(
        coordinates ? new Point([coordinates.lng, coordinates.lat]) : null,
      )
    })
}
```

Can somebody point me out what I did wrong here?
I already did follow this documentation https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/geolocation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did forget to format the coordinate like the following

```
  this._geolocationService.onUserPositionChanged$
    .pipe(takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll))
    .subscribe((coordinates) => {
      this.positionFeature.setGeometry(
        coordinates 
          ? new Point(olProj.fromLonLat([coordinates.lng, coordinates.lat])) 
          : null, // <-- Use olProj.fromLonLat() method
      )
    })
```